# How to simplify the process of evaluating cells with respect to the average value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to review each cell of my dataframe to check if each value is lower than 50% of the columns mean. I tried with the following code, but it is super inefficient and it get stuck.

```
for col, value in data.items():
    mean = data[col].mean()
    for i in value:
        for day in data.index:
            if i < 0.5 * mean:
                data.loc[day, col] = 0
```

How could I simplify or do it better?

The dataframe is the following one:

```
                  Log  1233.de  asdad.w.1  fff.op

Tagname                                          

01/06/2008 00:00    0   343.04      73.75   79.03

02/06/2008 00:00    0   332.31      73.71   79.21

03/06/2008 00:00    0   339.25      75.77   80.11

04/06/2008 00:00    0   353.25      76.47   79.75

05/06/2008 00:00    0   353.44      77.35   82.48
```

Which is uploaded as:

```
dat =  pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = 0, index_col = "Tagname")

data = pd.DataFrame(dat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is compare mean of all columns by `mean`, multiple by `0.5` and the compare by [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) with set `0` values by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
data = data.mask(data.lt(data.mean() * 0.5), 0)
```